# Calling base constructor - Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

There are 2 ways to call the parent constructor in the child.

```
var A = function A() {
  this.x = 123;
};

var B = function B() {

  // 1. call directly
  A.call(this);

  // 2. call from prototype
  A.prototype.constructor.call(this);
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Are there any situations when one would be safer/better than the other, or are they always equivalent?

Comment: What would compel you to use the second version? You're just taking a long path to get to the same function.

Comment: Maybe a situation where `A` inherited a constructor from another object?

Comment: Alright, but then the two calls are not equivalent. You're talking about two different situations.

Comment: Hence the last part of the question.

Comment: But if you're describing a situation where they are not equivalent, then you already know they may not be not equivalent, so why ask the question? If the situation is such that you know they *are* equivalent, then what would compel you to use the second version?

Comment: I had a rough idea, @Aadit reinforced/clarified it.

Comment: @iliacholy - From what I see you're doing in your code, perhaps you might find the following answer interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12041555/783743

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's always better to use the base constructor directly for the following reasons:

1. It's faster. The interpreter doesn't need to access `prototype.constructor`.
2. It's safer. Consider the program below.

`A` inherits from `C`, but I forgot to set `A.prototype.constructor` back to `A`. So it now points to `C`. This causes problems in the constructor `B` if we use the second method:

```
var C = function C() {
    // some code
};

var A = function A() {
  this.x = 123;
};

A.prototype = Object.create(C.prototype);
// I forgot to uncomment the next line:
// A.prototype.constructor = A;

var B = function B() {

  // 1. call directly
  A.call(this);

  // 2. call from prototype
  A.prototype.constructor.call(this); // A.prototype.constructor is C, not A
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```